# Echo out all field names along with their respective values

Tags: php, mysql, html

I would like to print a list with all field names and their values from a table in a mysql database. How would i use a loop to print:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
FIELD NAME
</td>
<td>
FIELD VALUE
</td>
</table
```

Any help would be appreciated

UPDATE

The first field is a unique_id, how would i skip the first field? Say echo all from the second field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic PHP, a simple while-loop combined with a foreach would suffice:

```
echo '<table>';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `your_table`");
// Loop over all result rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // Loop over all fields per row
    foreach($row as $field => $value) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . htmlentities($field) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($value) . '</td></tr>';
    }
    // New data row can optionally be seperated with a blank line here
    echo '<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: As this is for someone new to PHP, it's worth pointing out that if you're outputting something uncontrolled (for example, anything which originated from a user) , you should use htmlentities($value) rather than just $value. A useful habit to get into.

Comment: Thanks, the first field is a unique_id, how would i skip the first field? Say echo all from the second field

Comment: @SebastianOpperman You could either not select that field in your query or add a filter in the foreach around the echo, like so: if($field != 'id') { echo ... }

Comment: @Oldskool I forgot about the if statements i can use. Thanks that helped

Comment: You shouldn't select fields you don't intend to use. In fact, you hardly ever need SELECT * and it's more for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_field_name()`, `mysql_num_fields()`, `mysql_fetch_field()`, `mysql_field_seek()`.

Or `keys(mysql_fetch_assoc())`

Answer (score 0):

This is something I did a few days ago:

```
mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
mysql_select_db('database');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM  your_table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
$i = 0;
while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result))
{
    $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);   
    echo "<th>".$meta->name."</th>";
    $i++;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';

    foreach($row as $item)
    {
        echo "<td>".$item."</td>";
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo "</table>";
```