# Echo table from phpMyAdmin into html table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, phpmyadmin

How would you echo out a MySQL table into a html table. Like phpMyAdmin shows a table, just a basic table structure with the name of the fields and all the records in that table.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Seems very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978010/echo-out-all-field-names-along-with-their-respective-values ?

Comment: Yes, That question printed out my field names more than once with every new rocord added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code show the a dinamic table with all the field and all the rows returned from a query...

This works for all pourpose you need

- list all tables
- show table field description
- show all table rows

  ```
  <?php
   // list all the table in database
   $result = mysql_query("show tables");
   // show all the field with type, lenght,description of a specific table
   $result = mysql_query("DESCRIBE table_name");
   // show a specific tables row 
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
   if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
   $r = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
   $table="<table><tr>";
   $firstLine="<tr>";
   foreach ($r as $k => $v){
     $table .="<td>".$k."</td>";
     $firstLine .="<td>".$v."</td>";
   }
   $table.="</tr>".$firstLine."</tr>";
   while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
     $table.="<tr>";
     foreach($r as $k => $v)
       $table.="<td>".$v."</td>";
     $table.="</tr>";
   }
    $table .="</table>";
   echo $table;
  }
  ?>
  ```

Comment: This creates id fields before each <td> with duplicate data. it should only display each field name once.

Comment: sorry I edited, so now it only display the field name and not the id... try now :) I also added the query to show the table list and the table structure...

Comment: Hey @Sebastian can't you amend this code **yourself**? You know, this site is to answering questions, not for doing whole your job for free. Could you at least use some words like 'please'  instead of 'should'? You aren't an employer here to issue orders.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Sorry for the reply. I did not mean it in a demanding way.

Comment: Hi yes this worked thanks Marcx. I am basicaly trying to display a Mysql database as Myphpadmin would display it. I can display the field names or loop through the reocrds on their own but i cant get them to work together. This solution worked using variables containing html tags which solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

The SQL you're looking for is `SHOW TABLES` to show all tables in your current database and `DESCRIBE tablename` to show all columns and their information. You can execute that query and loop through the results to print your table layout.

If that's not what you're looking for, do you mean to (auto-)generate a forms for CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations, based on your table layout? Then you could look at something like [php scaffold](http://www.phpscaffold.com/) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>ID</th>
<?php
$query = "SELECT name, id FROM table";
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$name = $data['name'];
$id = $data['id'];
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$name.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$id.'</td>'; 
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

1. Create query that SELECT the data you want to retrieve
2. Enclose it in mysql_fetch_assoc() plus a while loop if your getting more than 1 row from your query.

Comment: This won't create an html table at all